# Uploading CSV file to Azure Data Lake Store(ADLS) Gen 2 using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

[UPDATE - 5/15/2020 - I got this code and the entire flow working with parquet file format. However,I would be still interested in the approach using CSV]

I am trying to upload a csv file from a local machine to ADLS Gen 2 storage using the below command. This works fine, but the resulting csv file in ADLS is a continuous text with no new line character to separate each row. This CSV file cannot be loaded into Azure Synapse as is using Polybase.

Input CSV -

"col1","col2","col3"

"NJ","1","1/3/2020"

"NY","1","1/4/2020"
...

Output CSV that I get is like this -

"col1","col2","col3""NJ","1","1/3/2020""NY","1","1/4/2020"...

How do i make sure my final csv has the new line character after each row? There are few 100,000 records in each CSVs.

```
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings

try:  
    global service_client
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https", "<storage-account>"), credential="<secret>")

    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="import")
    dest_directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("Destination")

    f = open("file-path/cashreceipts.csv",'r')

    dest_file_client = dest_directory_client.create_file("cashreceipts.csv")

    file_contents = f.read()

    dest_file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True)
    f.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I tried this approach as well -

```
dest_file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))
dest_file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))
```

I am referring to the Microsoft documentation here which describes the approach for a text file - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python

Comment: After you upload the csv file, the content likes col1","col2","col3""NJ","1","1/3/2020""NY","1","1/4/2020".... Right?

Comment: Yes! i feel the file read operation is reading it as a binary, that's where the problem is. If i were to read record by record and append the data, this is going to be time consuming.

Comment: You can try to read file as bytes ` f = open("file-path/cashreceipts.csv",'rb')`